# How to access sinatra class variable in coffeescript template

Tags: ruby, sinatra, coffeescript

How can I access ruby instance variable from within coffeescript template?

In sinatra documentation it's said that templates are evaluated within same scope as rout that invoke that template.

So, I have following sinatra app:

**server.rb**:

```
require "sinatra"
require "coffee-script"

get '/app.js' do
  @str = "Hello"
  coffee :app
end
```

and in views/app.coffe file I would like to use `@str`variable. Is it possible? If so, how can I access `@str` variable?

Answer (score 6):

It could be possible only if you'll process coffee source file with something like erb. So if you'd use rails assets pipeline you can just append .erb to file extension and the file will be processed with erb before sending it to coffee I think in sinatra you'll have to wrap up something similar yourself.

The idea will be close to this one - http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Textile%20Templates

P.S: accessing variables from different layers of application is bad idea anyway.

**EDIT**

You have  amultistage template compilation process in RAILS driven by a gem called sprockets. You start with a file for example called /app/views/foo/show.js.coffee.erb

```
class <%= @magic %>
    doSomthing: ->
        console.log "hello"
```

In your controller you add the instance variable

```
@magic = "Crazy"
```

Rails first processes the erb file and generates

```
class Crazy
    doSomething: ->
        console.log "hello"
```

Secondly it processes the coffeescript file to generate

```
var Crazy;
Crazy = (function() {
  function Crazy() {}
  Crazy.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    return console.log("hello");
  };
  return Crazy;
})();
```

That is why it is called the *asset pipeline*. More conventionally you could call it
a compilation pipeline. If you know what you are doing you might be able to get sprockets running with Sinatra. However your life would be easier if you just used Rails 3.1 from
the start.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. Maybe You know how could I pass locals to CoffeeScript? Documentation says nothing about it. I initially though that sinatra would treat coffee templates similar to haml templates, so it would be possible to create js same as html.

Comment: See my answer. You can't pass locals but you can preprocess coffee script source code with template engine before compiling it

Comment: iafonov and bradgonesurfing, big thanks! I have found that it's possible to do something like "coffee(erb :app)" and embed ruby code in coffee-script, eg "<%= @str %>". Just like you have said iafonov. The only downside is that file in "views" folder needs to be called "app.erb", IMHO hide true nature of file - that's why i have hacked my local sinatra gem and add new option ":preprocess", now i can do something like: "coffee :app, :preprocess => :erb" and save  template file as "views/app.coffee.erb". Works just like bradgonesurfing describe. Much better and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this for Rails: https://github.com/ludicast/ice

but it can be easily adapted for Sinatra.

It lets you use Eco and CoffeeKup templates inside a Rails application, with the ruby models exposed to Coffeescript.

Nate